# double values on mysql

Tags: mysql, database

hi i have a db schema like this:

```
poll_option:
+----+---------------------+
| question_id | option     |
+----+---------------------+
|      1      | forever    |
+----+---------------------+

poll_clicks:
+--------------------+------------+
| question| meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |     ip   |192.168.1.10| 
+---------+----------+------------+

result i want:
+--------------------+------------+
|  option | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+----------+------------+
| forever |     ip   |192.168.1.10| 
+---------+----------+------------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT p.* FROM poll_clicks p, poll_option m 
  WHERE m.question_id=p.question
```

but Im getting repeated values,
any ideas?

EDIT: just need to add the "option" to  "poll_click" result

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT p.* ...`?

Comment: Apparently there are a lot of poll_clicks per poll_option

Comment: Please show (with examples/expected out) what you mean with "repeated values".

Answer (score 0):

Your query is requesting all of the `poll_clicks` columns but your expected result has values from both tables.

As for "repeated values", if you mean you're getting multiple rows then there's only one way that can happen: one or both of the tables has duplicate `question` or `question_id` values.

To get the proper columns, the query should start like this:

```
SELECT m.option, p.meta_key, p.meta_value
...
```

Your join is correct, but it uses ancient syntax. Try doing it like this instead - it has the same effect as your join but it isolates the join logic from any other `WHERE` logic you might have:

```
SELECT m.option, p.meta_key, p.meta_value
FROM poll_clicks p
JOIN poll_option m ON m.question_id = p.question
```

Comment: I want to add the option from poll_option to the results from the poll_clicks

Comment: Sorry @greenbandit but I don't fully understand your question. Could you post a few more rows of sample data (for each table) with expected results? One row for each table doesn't help much - it's not even clear why you need a separate `poll_option` table. Could you also clarify what you mean by "repeated values"?

Comment: What i need is this select * from poll_clicks and only add the relationated option for every result from above query.

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT p.*, m.option FROM ...`?

Comment: i want to make the select * from poll_clicks and the select option from poll_option in one query with unique results

Comment: Sorry @greenbandit, I still don't get it. Can you try my earlier suggestion of posting more than one `poll_option` row and more than one `poll_clicks` row, along with expected results? Most likely I can help, but not until I understand what you want.